# How to convert MapDataset variable into np.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

## Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6.8
- Tensorflow 1.12.0

## The problem

I want to convert the data with MapDataset class into numpy.array to check the contents.

### Data detail

I have data as TFRecord. This data contains images (150x150x3) and labels (1 or 0). This TFRecord was created from the following code.

```py
def int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

np.random.seed(42)
rnd_index = np.random.permutation(len(image_paths))
X_train, y_train = image_paths[rnd_index[:-1000]], labels[rnd_index[:-1000]]
X_test, y_test = image_paths[rnd_index[-1000:]], labels[rnd_index[-1000:]]

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('training.tfrecord')

for image_path, label in zip(X_train, y_train):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (150, 150)) / 255.0
    img_raw = image.tostring()
    ex = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={                                                                     
                        'image': bytes_feature(img_raw),
                        'label': int64_feature(label)
                         }))
    writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

### Parsing data

I parsed the data by following code.

```py
def parse(example_proto):
    features = {
        'label' : tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'image' : tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)
    }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    img_shape = tf.stack([150, 150, 3])
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image'], tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, img_shape)
    label = tf.cast(parsed_features['label'], tf.int32)
    return image, label


with tf.Session() as sess:
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('training.tfrecord')
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
```

I want to get the image from 'dataset' variable, but I don't know how to do.

I tried running the following code on the jupyter notebook.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('training.tfrecord')
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    elem = next_element[0].eval()

dataset
```

But I got the error message.

```sh
InvalidArgumentError: Feature: image (data type: string) is required but could not be found.
     [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample}} = ParseSingleExample[Tdense=[DT_STRING, DT_INT64], dense_keys=["image", "label"], dense_shapes=[[], []], num_sparse=0, sparse_keys=[], sparse_types=[]](arg0, ParseSingleExample/Const, ParseSingleExample/Const_1)]]
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at <ipython-input-3-350cc5050691>:19)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[150,150,3], []], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]
```

I'm a beginner of Tensorflow, so I cannot understand what this message means, and how to deal with it.

Comment: Checked the code exactly as it's written. Works fine. How `X_train` and  `y_train` look like?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.

Comment: In the code I added now, the 'image_paths' variable is a list of string that has paths to the jpeg images, and 'labels' variable is a list of integer (0 or 1)

Comment: Make sure you have a valid image for `cv2.imread`. And maki it `image = cv2.imread(image_path).astype(np.float32) / 255` Don't do resize while converting

Comment: I can read image from image_path by cv2, and I tried not resizing while converting, but the error message does not change.

Comment: Actually, I use the dataset in Kaggle. I made my public notebook.https://www.kaggle.com/yuhaya9/kernel9068633942?scriptVersionId=12233745